# Как лучше и правильнее передать данные из javascript в сервлет, если не использовать форму и input

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlet

Задача стандартная, корзина на сайте. Продукты подгружаются динамически. Хочу сделать чтобы при клике на кнопку "В корзину", происходила передача двух параметров в сервлет (это id, который я беру у кнопки и count, количество товара). Как их правильно передать в сервлет? Которые хотелось бы в сервлете получить через 
request.getParametr("id");

```js
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var send = "{\"id\":" + "\"" + id + "\"," + "\"count\":" + "\"" + count + "\"" + "}";
    send = JSON.parse(send);

    function reqReadyStateChange() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            var status = xhr.status;
            if (status == 200) {
                var data = xhr.responseText;
            }
            else {
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.open("POST", srvUrl, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = reqReadyStateChange;
    xhr.send(send);
}
```

Пробовал вот так, но servlet возвращает null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON нужно не парсить при отправке, а наоборот привести к строке "stringify", и еще можно добавить в хедер MIME type

```
var send = JSON.stringify({ id, count });
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");
xhr.open("POST", srvUrl, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { /* some handler */ };
xhr.send(send);
```

Comment: спасибо, уже разобрался. Просто обычную строку нужно было получать с помощью конструкции. BufferedReader json = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String line = null;
        String str = new String();
        while ((line = json.readLine()) != null) {
            str += line;
        } А далее разобрать его в GSON.